# Is there a different way to scrape this with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm trying to scrape the tables off [this website for NBA teams in years past](https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/BOS/1980.html) and I'm trying to get a specific table off of it. I really just know how to scrape tables with pandas read_html function, so I've been doing that. When I used the length function, pandas told me there were only 5 tables, when there really are 14. [image: This is the image I want to get the data off of] This is the image that I want to get the data off, but Pandas doesn't think that this exists. The code that I used was as follows:

```
import pandas as pd 

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/BOS/1980.html"

tables= pd.read_html(url)
```

So when I run it, I look through all the tables and I only get 5 tables. Can anyone help?

Comment: Turn off javascript on your browser then reload the page.  You will see the table does not exist.  it's built dynamically using javascript which mean it has to be built in browser, so you will need to use something like selenium to scrape it

Answer (score 1):

- switch off javascript on your browser, reload the page
- table is not displayed.  View source and you will see table is commented out
- can navigate to commented sections of HTML using **BeautifulSoup**
- push this HTML into `pd.read_html()`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment
import pandas as pd
res = requests.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/BOS/1980.html")
id="div_team_and_opponent"
html = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
pd.read_html(html.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment) and id in text)[0])[0]
```

|  | Unnamed: 0 | G | MP | FG | FGA | FG% | 3P | 3PA | 3P% | 2P | 2PA | 2P% | FT | FTA | FT% | ORB | DRB | TRB | AST | STL | BLK | TOV | PF | PTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Team | 82 | 19880 | 3617 | 7387 | 0.49 | 162 | 422 | 0.384 | 3455 | 6965 | 0.496 | 1907 | 2449 | 0.779 | 1227 | 2457 | 3684 | 2198 | 809 | 308 | 1539 | 1974 | 9303 |
| 1 | Team/G | nan | 242.4 | 44.1 | 90.1 | 0.49 | 2 | 5.1 | 0.384 | 42.1 | 84.9 | 0.496 | 23.3 | 29.9 | 0.779 | 15.0 | 30.0 | 44.9 | 26.8 | 9.9 | 3.8 | 18.8 | 24.1 | 113.5 |
| 2 | Lg Rank | nan | 4 | 8 | 14 | 7 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 15 | 17 | 7 | 4 | 6 | 5 | 13 | 10 | 11 | 8 | 6 | 21 | 11 | 13 | 5 |
| 3 | Year/Year | nan | 1.0% | 2.6% | 0.5% | 0.009 | nan | nan | nan | -2.0% | -5.2% | 0.016 | 4.8% | 5.5% | -0.005 | 9.7% | 2.5% | 4.8% | 10.2% | 13.9% | 8.8% | -10.2% | -0.2% | 4.8% |
| 4 | Opponent | 82 | 19880 | 3439 | 7313 | 0.47 | 74 | 259 | 0.286 | 3365 | 7054 | 0.477 | 1712 | 2222 | 0.77 | 1168 | 2294 | 3462 | 1867 | 686 | 419 | 1635 | 2059 | 8664 |
| 5 | Opponent/G | nan | 242.4 | 41.9 | 89.2 | 0.47 | 0.9 | 3.2 | 0.286 | 41.0 | 86.0 | 0.477 | 20.9 | 27.1 | 0.77 | 14.2 | 28.0 | 42.2 | 22.8 | 8.4 | 5.1 | 19.9 | 25.1 | 105.7 |
| 6 | Lg Rank | nan | 4 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 17 | 17 | 15 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 11 | 10 | 17 | 6 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 11 | 9 | 6 | 6 |
| 7 | Year/Year | nan | 1.0% | -10.8% | -3.7% | -0.037 | nan | nan | nan | -12.7% | -7.1% | -0.031 | 8.5% | 6.9% | 0.011 | 4.1% | -6.5% | -3.2% | -14.0% | -4.3% | -4.3% | 2.0% | 1.7% | -6.7% |